# LVM2: How to copy snapshots?

Tags: linux, lvm, snapshot, copy, clone

I read [What does an LVM2 Snapshot contain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/498541/what-does-an-lvm2-snapshot-contain) and [LVM Snapshot confusion](https://serverfault.com/questions/499076/lvm-snapshot-confusion/499078#499078).

What I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way to create a copy of an LVM snapshot for use with different Xen VMs. I know that it isn't built into LVM (yet), but I was wondering if it might (or might not) work like this:

1. Create Logical Volume LV1
2. Create Snapshot1 of LV1 (100MB)
3. Create Snapshot2 of LV1 (100MB)
4. dd if=Snapshot1 of=Snapshot2
5. Use Snapshot1 and Snapshot2 both for R/W operations with Xen, use LV1 read-only.

Would it work or would it fail horribly in hard-to-detect ways? Any other suggestions to approach this? I guess that I could also create a second Logical Volume LV2 and copy the content of Snapshot2, but that would take up more space for PEs.

**Solution:**

In the meantime I found a way to do it using LVM2 thin volumes: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LVM#LVM2_Thin_Snapshots

Comment: What's the `dd` for?

Comment: Well, the idea is that I have made changes to Snapshot1 after creating it. I now want Snapshot2 to start out with the same content as Snapshot1, so I use dd initially to clone these two devices.

Comment: Why don't you ... you know ... make a snapshot?

Comment: LVM2 does not yet support snapshots of snapshots. First thing I tried obviously ;)

Answer (score 1):

The idea may be reasonable but dd is the killer for all efforts.
You will not get neither speed nor space-saving.

With differential coping at least space-saving may available.
Can try  [lvmsync](http://theshed.hezmatt.org/lvmsync/) to do It.

Another option is ZFS ([zfsonlinux](http://zfsonlinux.org)) where you can
do clones from snapshots. But I am not sure about ZVOL perfomance
on Linux.